# Как реализовать масштабирование gridview?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

Есть идея реализовать японский кроссворд такого вида:
[image: Кроссворд]

Используя GridView можно без проблем вывести большое количество элементов, к примеру 1000.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но, возникает вопрос с масштабированием. Можно ли увеличивать сетку пальцами, есть ли какие то для этого методы? Или выбранный путь изначально неверный и следует использовать другой подход?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать это при помощи 
listView(или GrieView).setOnItemClickListener
и задать switch(position)
и добавить метод зумирования пальцами и все.
здесь верных путей нет . есть пути которые тебе покажутся легкими или сложными .

Comment: можно пожалуйста поподробнее про метод зумирования пальцами?

Comment: вот тебе библиотека  https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: ка раз под твой случай) если мой ответ поможет найти решение жми палец вверх на ответе )